# Casting char* -> QString, Readability or clarity? (C++/Qt)

Tags: c++, qt, casting

I 'm trying to add `testclasses` to an existing Qt Project and I came across this question:

```
void doSomething (QString str, int i) {..}

int main () {
    //Do I use
    doSomething("string", 0);
    //Or
    doSomething(QString("string"), 0);
}
```

If I'm not mistaken it does the same internally, as it casts the `char*` implicitly with the `QString(char* c)` constructor.

But which way is preferred?

I personally like the implicit cast, as it's easier to read than the constructor call, but in my C++ book I read, that implicit casting should be avoided if possible.

Comment: maybe it will be usefull: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437241/c-always-use-explicit-constructor

Comment: Do you actually use other strings (like `std::string') elsewhere ? Are you afraid it is going to be confusing ? "Readability counts" and "Practicality beats purity". Don't overthink it, and don't generalize the answer to this question to other cases.

Comment: `QStringLiteral()` to avoid runtime decoding.

Comment: @Félix QString is used in the whole program. I don't know the pros and cons for String vs QString, as I'm still a beginner. I was just curious, as C++ provides a lot more ways to handle object creation and managing and casts as opposed to Java, which I worked with more.

Comment: QString offer a lot more convenience methods that std::string. It has a split method for instance. If you only use QString, it isn't necessary to explicity create a QString here.

Answer (score 4):

Actually if you are using Qt5, the better approach is `QStringLiteral()`. It not only signifies the intent (a compile time constant `QString`), but also (slightly) increase efficiency because no runtime conversion from some mulitbyte encoding to UTF-16 is required.

If you need to use Qt4, then conditionally defines it yourself:

```
#ifndef QStringLiteral
#define QStringLiteral(x) (QString::fromUtf8(x))
#endif
```

Or as commented by Kuba Ober, add

```
lessThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5): DEFINES += QStringLiteral=QString::fromUtf8
```

to your .pro file.

Quoted from Qt Documentation:

> The macro generates the data for a QString out of str at compile time
>   if the compiler supports it. Creating a QString from it is free in
>   this case, and the generated string data is stored in the read-only
>   segment of the compiled object file.
>
> For compilers not supporting the creation of compile time strings,
>   QStringLiteral will fall back to QString::fromUtf8().
>
> If you have code looking like:

```
 if (node.hasAttribute("http-contents-length")) //...
```

> One temporary QString will be created to be passed as the hasAttribute function
>   parameter. This can be quite expensive, as it involves a memory
>   allocation and the copy and the conversion of the data into QString's
>   internal encoding.
>
> This can be avoided by doing

```
if (node.hasAttribute(QStringLiteral("http-contents-length"))) //...
```

> Then the QString's internal data will be generated at compile time and
>   no conversion or allocation will occur at runtime
>
> Using QStringLiteral instead of a double quoted ascii literal can
>   significantly speed up creation of QString's from data known at
>   compile time.
>
> If the compiler is C++11 enabled the string str can actually contain
>   unicode data.

Comment: I just looked up QStringLiteral. I thought it was some kind of new class, but it is a makro, right? I'll probably use and comment it shortly, if someone wonders what it does.

Comment: @LucaFülbier: It is a macro that evaluates to some magic, which will in turn statically construct your `QString`.

Comment: Another alternative: add `lessThan(QT_MAJOR_VERSION, 5): DEFINES += QStringLiteral=QString::fromUtf8` to your `.pro` file.

Answer (score 2):

Actually in case of Qt the answer is neither. You should use `QObject::tr()` instead. You may not need translation in every project, but it is much better to have right habit, rather than look through source later and fix it.

If translation of that string is not necessary I recommend to use `QString` [static functions](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qstring.html#fromAscii) `QString::fromAscii()`, `QString::fromLatin1()` or `QString::fromLocal8Bit()` instead of implicit or explicit cast:

```
int main () {
    doSomething( QString::fromAscii( "string" ), 0);
}
```

Comment: The usage of tr() function depends on the context. Usually, I translate only the strings displayed to user, not necessary all the strings in the program. You don't have any information on this kind of context in the question. But the remark is interesting to notice.

Comment: I came across tr() too, but didn't use it as it was no user visible string. Are there advantages of using the static functions, or is it for understanding only?

Answer (score 0):

As you said, if the first parameter of doSomething() method is a QString, the right object will be initialized if you pass a 'const char *', this is more clear, easier to read, and the result is the same.

Your book said you should avoid implicit casting, and it is not a bad advice. In many cases in C++, you will probably be confused by automatic (and hidden) behaviors. But if you write a program using Qt frameworks, you will maybe choose to use QString instead of std::string or char* in most case. I think the implicit conversion is sufficiently explicit and should not cause any trouble in your development.

Comment: That's what i guessed. Thank you!