# C++ template compilation causes "recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024"

Tags: c++, templates

```cpp
#include <type_traits>

template <typename T>
struct Point2 {
  Point2() = default;
  Point2(const T& x, const T& y) : x(x), y(y) {}

  template <typename U>
  Point2(const U& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) {}
  
  template<typename U>
  friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(const Point2<T>& vec, U scale) {
    return {vec.x * scale, vec.y * scale};
  }
  
  template<typename U>
  friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(U scale, const Point2<T>& vec) {
    return {vec.x * scale, vec.y * scale};
  }

  T x;
  T y;
};

int main() {
  Point2<double> a;
  double b;
  auto c = a * b;
}
```

I'm trying to compile the above code with `clang-16` and option `-std=c++17`.

However, there is a compilation error:

```
ce.cpp:4:8: warning: stack nearly exhausted; compilation time may suffer, and crashes due to stack overflow are likely [-Wstack-exhausted]
struct Point2 {
       ^
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
  friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(const Point2<T>& vec, U scale) {
                             ^
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: (skipping 472 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:17:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
  friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(U scale, const Point2<T>& vec) {
                             ^
ce.cpp:28:14: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
  auto c = a * b;
             ^
ce.cpp:12:26: fatal error: recursive template instantiation exceeded maximum depth of 1024
  friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(const Point2<T>& vec, U scale) {
                         ^
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
  friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(const Point2<T>& vec, U scale) {
                             ^
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: (skipping 1015 contexts in backtrace; use -ftemplate-backtrace-limit=0 to see all)
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
ce.cpp:17:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
  friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(U scale, const Point2<T>& vec) {
                             ^
ce.cpp:28:14: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
  auto c = a * b;
             ^
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Why does the compiler deduce the types with: `U = Point2<double>`?

It's very obvious the type `U` should be `double`, right?

Actually, I can find a lot of ways to correct this compilation error.

Solution 1: Comment the template constructor

```
  ...
  // template <typename U>
  // Point2(const U& other) : x(other.x), y(other.y) {}
  ...
```

Solution 2: Directly using `auto` instead of `decltype` to deduce the return type for `either` operator*

```
  ...
  template<typename U>
  friend auto operator*(const Point2<T>& vec, U scale) {
    return Point2{vec.x * scale, vec.y * scale};
  }
  ...
```

or

```
  ...
  template<typename U>
  friend auto operator*(U scale, const Point2<T>& vec) {
    return Point2{vec.x * scale, vec.y * scale};
  }
  ...
```

I can roughly think of a very suspicious aspect is the `decltype(T() * U())`, but I can not explain it very clearly.

Can anybody figure it out?

Alao, let me repeat the most confusing question for me：

`Why does the compiler deduce the types with: U = Point2<double> ?`

Comment: Unrelated: `b` is uninitialized and you're passing it by value so undefined behavior.

Comment: *"Why does the compiler deduce the types with: U = Point2<double> ? "* Because you have provided a templated converting constructor `template <typename U> Point2(const U& other)` that is used to first convert the argument `b` from `double` to `Point2<double>`

Comment: Basically you have a templated converting ctor that is used to convert `b` to `Point2<double>`. There are **two ways to solve this**: 1) mark it as `explicit` or 2) remove it completely as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77520239/12002570).

Comment: *"It's very obvious the type `U` should be `double`, right?"* -- Wrong. Well, unless you're going for "obvious" meaning "I want this false thing to be true without evidence". *More precisely, in `auto c = a * b;` the type of `a` is `Point2<double>`, so "obviously" the the type, `U`, of the first parameter to `operator*` is `Point2<double>`. If you're now thinking "Wait, what?", pay attention to details, and don't be blinded by your intended meaning.*

Comment: @user12002570 Thanks for your answer, very helpful. I can roughly got the meaning of `converting constructor` you mentioned here. But I still have one question: the `double` doesn't have members named `x` and `y`, so how could this `converting constructor` be eligible? Also, Can I have some thing like the SFINAE to check if the constructor eligible or not?

Comment: @kaixinliu Note that `double` doesn't have to have members named `x` and `y` for the converting constructor to be eligible. Eligibility is solely dependent on the parameter list of the constructor, that is only `(const U& other)` is checked for eligibility of the converting constructor but not the initializer list `x(other.x), y(other.y)` because the member initializer list is not part of the parameter list of the constructor.

Comment: @user12002570 Got it! Is this rule you mentioned belongs to ISO C++ standard? Or it's a compiler-releated feature(I've also tried the x86 trunk gcc, gcc11, gcc7, both got stucked...)?

Comment: @kaixinliu It's part of ISO C++ standard and is not a compiler feature/extension.

Comment: @user12002570 Wonderful! May I know which section of the ISO C++ standard it belongs to? It's quite hard for me to find it  out ... Thanks in advance!

Comment: @kaixinliu [temp.deduct] has the rules. Also, for further read [Why mark constructor taking one parameter `explicit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437241/c-always-use-explicit-constructor)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/256003/discussion-between-kaixin-liu-and-user12002570).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's what happens in overload resolution for the expression `a * b`:

1. Find the candidate functions and function templates for the function `operator*`, when the arguments are an lvalue of type `Point2<double>` and an lvalue of type `double`. No built-in meanings of `operator*` are viable. Since one argument has class type `Point2<double>`, its two friend templates are candidates:

   ```
   template<typename U>
   Point2<decltype(double() * U())>
   operator*(const Point2<double>&, U);  // (A)

   template<typename U>
   Point2<decltype(double() * U())>
   operator*(U, const Point2<double>&);  // (B)
   ```
2. Attempt template argument deduction for each candidate template. Template (A) finds `U = double`. Template (B) finds `U = Point2<double>`.
3. Substitute the template arguments to determine the function types.

   ```
   Point2<decltype(double() * double())>
   operator*(const Point2<double>&, double);         // (A1)

   Point2<decltype(double() * Point2<double>())>
   operator*(Point2<double>, const Point2<double>&); // (B1)
   ```

   Both are okay so far, since (B1) can be called by implicit conversion from `double` to `Point2<double>` via the `template <typename U> Point2(const U&);` constructor.

   But that hasn't entirely determined the function types. The return types are part of the function type. For (A1), no problem, `decltype(double() * double())` is `double`, so the return type is `Point2<double>`. For (B1), determining the type `decltype(double() * Point2<double>())` requires overload resolution.
4. Find the candidate functions and function templates for `operator*`. This time the arguments are a prvalue of type `double` and a prvalue of type `Point2<double>`. The same two function templates (A) and (B) are candidates.
5. Attempt template argument deduction for each candidate template. Template (A) finds `U = Point2<double>`. Template (B) finds `U = double`.
6. Substitute the template arguments to determine the function types.

   ```
   Point2<decltype(double() * Point2<double>())>
   operator*(const Point2<double>&, Point2<double>); // (A2)

   Point2<decltype(double() * double()>
   operator*(double, const Point2<double>&);         // (B2)
   ```

   Like (B1) above, (A2) is okay so far because of the implicit conversion. The return type of (B2) is `double`. Determining the return type of (A2) requires overload resolution.
7. Find the candidate functions and function templates for `operator*`. This time the arguments are a prvalue of type `double` and a prvalue of type `Point2<double>`....

Uh oh. Steps 4 and 7 are both trying to figure out `decltype(double() * Point2<double>())`, which would be the return type of both (A1) and (B2). This process will never end, since that type ends up depending on itself.

Some ways to improve the situation without losing the functionality you apparently want:

- Mark constructor `template<typename U> Point2(const U&);` as `explicit`. It's generally a good idea to apply `explicit` to any constructor other than copy/move which can be called with one argument (including situations where all parameters after the first have default arguments, and variadic templates).
- Limit the possible instantiations of templates by SFINAE techniques.

  - Do you really want the template constructor to claim `Point2<T>` can be initialized with any type `U` at all? Or just other `Point2<U>` specializations? Or at least, `U` needs to be a class which has accessible members `x` and `y`...
  - The `operator*` functions could check that the parameter intended to be a scalar is *not* a `Point2` specialization.

Answer (score 2):

> Why does the compiler deduce the types with: `U = Point2<double>` ?

Because you have provided a **templated converting constructor** `template <typename U> Point2(const U& other)` that is used to first convert the argument `b` from `double` to `Point2<double>`. After this the overloaded `operator*` is used with parameter `U` deduced to `Point2<double>`.

---

You can solve this(and also verify this in the process) by either marking the  the templated constructor `explicit` or completely removing it as shown below:

##### Method 1

Here we mark the templated ctor `explicit`:

```
template <typename T>
struct Point2 {
  Point2() = default;
  Point2(const T& x, const T& y) : mx(x), my(y) {}

  template <typename U>
//vvvvvvvv------------------------------------>NOTE THE EXPLICIT
  explicit Point2(const U& other) : mx(other.x), my(other.y) {}
  
  //other overloads as before

  T mx;
  T my; 
};
```

[Working Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/vbMx7vqPj)

---

##### Method 2

Here we remove the templated ctor.

```
template <typename T>
struct Point2 {
  Point2() = default;
  Point2(const T& x, const T& y) : mx(x), my(y) {}

  //REMOVED TEMPLATED CTOR FROM HERe
  template<typename U>
  friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(const Point2<T>& vec, U scale) {
    return {};
  }
  
  template<typename U>
  friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(U scale, const Point2<T>& vec) {
    return {};
  }
```

[Working demo](https://godbolt.org/z/xzbzaPhzq).

---

**Note**

The variable `b` initialized and you're passing it by value, so the program currently has undefined behavior.

For further read: [Why mark constructor taking one parameter `explicit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437241/c-always-use-explicit-constructor)

Answer (score 1):

Here is an example that will compile AND it will restrict the Point class and the multiplication operator to only accept scalar types (integer and floating point types). When you used U() and V() the compiler deduced you where referring to functions U and V, so use U{} and V{} to work on instances of U and V to calculate the type of the resulting multiplication

```
#include <type_traits>

// Points should only be multiplyable by a scalar
// so add a trait to check if U is a scalar type
template<typename U>
constexpr bool is_scalar_v = (std::is_integral_v<U> || std::is_floating_point_v<U>) && (!std::is_same_v<bool,U>);

// enable SFINAE for Point2 class 
// you'd only want Point2 to work with scalar types (not std::string or anything)
template<typename T, typename enable_t = void> struct Point2 {};

// Calculate the type for a point based on T and U (T being the point type, and U being the scalar type)
// this can be an "invalid type" when U is not scalar
template<typename T, typename U>
using resulting_point_t = std::enable_if_t<is_scalar_v<T> && is_scalar_v<U>, Point2<decltype(T{}*U{})>>;

// Only enable Point2 for scalar types
template <typename T>
struct Point2<T,std::enable_if_t<is_scalar_v<T>>> final
{
    Point2() = default;

    Point2(T x, T y) :
        x{x},
        y{y}
    {
    }

    // implicit conversion constructors are not recommended so use explicit
    template <typename U>
    explicit Point2(const Point2<U>& other) : 
        x{other.x}, 
        y{other.y} 
    {
    }
    
    // operator* will now only compile (resulting_point_t<T,U> will only be a valid type when
    // U is a scalar type, so no need to pass by reference
    template<typename U>
    friend auto operator*(const Point2<T>& vec, U scale) -> resulting_point_t<T,U>
    {
        return { vec.x * scale, vec.y * scale };
    }

    template<typename U>
    friend auto operator*(U scale, const Point2<T>& vec) -> resulting_point_t<T,U>
    {
        return { vec.x * scale, vec.y * scale };
    }

    T x;
    T y;
};

int main() 
{
    static_assert(std::is_same_v<double, decltype(double{}*double{})>);
    static_assert(is_scalar_v<double>);

    Point2<double> a{1.0,2.0};
    double b{3.0};
    auto c = a * b;
}
```

Comment: `decltype(T() * U())` is not a Most Vexing Parse, since the syntax inside `decltype` can never be a type-specifier, only an expression (or the single token `auto`). Using `decltype(T{} * U{})` is still a better habit, yes.

Comment: @aschepler Ok thanks for that (some habit kicking in here I guess) ;)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers give a direct answer, so I'll take a look at the error message. In this case, it doesn't matter if we focus on the warning or the error; I'll go with the warning because it was emitted first.

> ```
> ce.cpp:4:8: warning: stack nearly exhausted; compilation time may suffer, and crashes due to stack overflow are likely [-Wstack-exhausted]
> struct Point2 {
>        ^
> ```

Okay, that's bad. We don't want that, but what actually happened? We know it has to deal with `Point2`, but what exactly is wrong? The bad news is that error messages for templates tend to be rather verbose. It often helps to switch gears; we had been looking at the first thing (the first warning), but now we'll look at the *last* thing (the last note for the first warning).

> ```
> ce.cpp:28:14: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
>   auto c = a * b;
>              ^
> ```

Good, this tells us where the warning "really" occurred. The final line points to the asterisk, so `operator*` is a key piece. This is supported by the text of the note, which also mentions `operator*`. And we have arrived at the thing that confused you: "U = Point2". Why is that? Let's go up another note.

> ```
> ce.cpp:17:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
>   friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(U scale, const Point2<T>& vec) {
>                              ^
> ```

If you're observant, you might notice that this line differs from the ones above it. This note applies to line **17**, not line 12. For the less observant, the declaration is provided. Note the parameter order: `U scale` *then* `const Point2<T>& vec`. *This is the **second** `operator*`.*

Once you realize that this line is for the second `operator*`, the deduction is clear. *([Terminology note](https://stackoverflow.com/q/156767): the "parameters" are `scale` and `vec`, while the "arguments" are `a` and `b`.)* The type of the first argument is `Point2<double>` so that is what `U` deduces to. It might, though, still be a mystery to you why this overload is being considered when the type of the second argument is `double`, not `Point2<T>`. It's a good mystery to look into, and the other answers explore it. Let's return to the compiler's notes.

This note also has a handy pointer in the last line, directing attention to the asterisk in the return type. This should tell you that the note above this one is a result of trying to determine the return type, which happens to again involve `operator*`, but this is different than the `operator*` that triggered the warning (i.e. `a * b`). **The types of the arguments are reversed.**

At this stage, the type of the *second* argument is `Point2<double>` so that is what `U` deduces to in the **first** `operator*` definition. The remaining notes cover this.

> ```
> ce.cpp:12:30: note: while substituting deduced template arguments into function template 'operator*' [with U = Point2<double>]
>   friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(const Point2<T>& vec, U scale) {
>                              ^
> ```

This is pretty much the same situation as before, but this time the return type does not reverse the order of the (previously reversed) operands. The type second argument is again `Point2<double>` so when the first overload is again considered, `U` is again deduced to that type. Thus we get the infinite "recursion" that exhausted the stack.

---

From this analysis, I would draw the conclusion that your `U` template parameter is too permissive. It looks like you intended it to be an arithmetic type, so specify that.

```cpp
  template<typename U> requires std::is_arithmetic_v<U>
  //                   ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  friend Point2<decltype(T() * U())> operator*(U scale, const Point2<T>& vec) {
    return {vec.x * scale, vec.y * scale};
  }
```

Note that you might want to apply this same restriction to `T` so that the compiler will not attempt to define things like `Point2<std::string>` or `Point2<Point2<double>>`.

(I also recommend marking the constructor `explicit`, as suggested by other answers.)