# Unexpected infinite recursion in C++ constructors

Tags: c++, constructor

A minimal example is:

```cpp
#include <vector>

class A {
private:
    // where the real initialization happens
    void constructor_impl(int);
    void constructor_impl(const A&);

public:
    A(const auto&... args) {
        (constructor_impl(args), ...);
    }
};

int main() {
    A{0, A{1, 2}}; // correct construction
    A{""}; // wrong construction: compiles to an infinite recursion
}
```

I expect the wrong call `A{""}` to raise a compile error. But instead the compiler tries to cast `""` to `A` and [generates an infinite recursion](https://godbolt.org/z/73cfxda1M). GCC, Clang and MSVC generates similar results, so it's unlikely to be a compiler bug.

Why does it happen? How can I refactor my code to avoid this issue?

Comment: It's not a compliler bug, you have allowed implicit conversions. Declare the constructors explicit.

Comment: @273K I don't think explicit will solve the issue, since the `void constructor_impl` method is private, and not an actual constructor.
Try to better the define the actual (public) constructor, and not make it as general (i.e., without auto).

Comment: @Amit What do you mean? The member functions `constructor_impl` are not constructors. Making the only constructor explicit makes the code ill-formed, as it's desired.

Comment: What `constructor_impl` do you expect `A{""}` to use? `""` isn't convertible to `int`, so converting it to `A` seems to be the only possible way out.

Comment: A suggestion to title, add `due to implicit conversion` might help future reader.

Comment: [When to make constructor explicit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437241/c-always-use-explicit-constructor)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your templated constructor is effectively a single argument constructor which accepts arguments of any type, therefore any type is implicitly convertible to `A`. Therefore when `A` is passed any argument which isn't `int` or `A` the compiler will attempt to call `void constructor_impl(const A&);` via an implicit conversion. As you say this leads to infinite recursion.

To avoid this problem you should mark the constructor as `explicit`:

```
explicit A(const auto&... args) {
```

This will prevent any implicit conversions to `A` and give you the compiler error you expect. In general, all single argument constructors should be marked `explicit` to avoid surprising implicit conversions.